# Comparing 2 hive tables for finding updated/inserted/deleted records without any unique column/timestamp and appending it to base table in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

> Base_table (Day 01 load from source)

```
 **Id    Name    City      Country** 
 7682   Stuart  Frankfurt   Germany
 8723   Micke   Paris       France
 2355   Niki    New york    USA
 2097   Deny    Italy       Rome
```

> new_table (Day 02 load from source)

```
 **Id    Name    City      Country** 
 7682   Stuart  *Darmstadt*  Germany
 8723   Micke   Paris       France
 2355   Niki    New york    USA
 *9057  Bony    Prague      Prague*
```

When comparing the above 2 tables the below 3 changes are seen.

> 1. Record Id 7682's City name changed to Darmstadt in Day 02 load
> 2. Record Id 2097 is deleted in Day 02 load and it was present in Day 01 load
> 3. New Record inserted with Id 9057 on Day 02 load

All the above 3 changes needs to be captured and appended into the Base_table

> Below 3 records should be captured out of comparision

```
7682   Stuart  Darmstadt   Germany
2097   Deny    Italy       Rome
9057   Bony    Prague      Prague
```

> Base_table output after appending Day 02 changes

```
**Id    Name    City      Country** 
 7682   Stuart  Frankfurt   Germany
 8723   Micke   Paris       France
 2355   Niki    New york    USA
 2097   Deny    Italy       Rome
*7682   Stuart  Darmstadt   Germany*   
*2097   Deny    Italy       Rome*
*9057   Bony    Prague      Prague*
```

I am able to get the insert and deleted records using SQL joins but unable to get the updated records. For getting updated records i used locally copying the files to linux and doing a comparison but its not apt for large volume of data. Can anyone please share your experience in handling this type of scenario?

Comment: The requested output does not make any sense

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Added the exact output(3 records) required after doing the comparison.

Comment: This was already clear as you can see in my two answers. It is not clear what is the point of getting the diff without any indication to the operation 
 (insert/delete/update) and more than that, what is the point appending the diff to the base table.

Comment: Appending the records in base_table is for maintaining historical values of each records i.e., versioning of records.

Comment: So you identify that a record was deleted from the base table and then you insert it into the base table without any indication that this is a actually deleted record?

Comment: Actual flow --> RDBMS to Hadoop every day load. Source RDBMS doesn't track the older versions of records they have only the recent change. In order track those info am doing the comparison between Day 1 load(base_table) vs Day 2, 3 .. n etc everyday and append the changes to base_table.

Comment: The Source table does not have a last update ts column?

Comment: Yes you are right. if it is available Sqoop incremental append can handle this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      inline
            (
                array
                (
                    case 
                        when n.id is null then struct(b.*)
                        else struct (n.*)
                    end
                )
            )

from                    base_table  as b
            full join   new_table   as n
            on          n.id = b.id

where       b.id is null 
        or  n.id is null
        or  struct(b.*) not in (struct(n.*))
```

---

```
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
| col1 |  col2  |   col3    |  col4   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
| 2097 | Deny   | Italy     | Rome    |
| 7682 | Stuart | Darmstadt | Germany |
| 9057 | Bony   | Prague    | Prague  |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you add an explanation on how the update records are handled in the above query.

Comment: `struct(*)` is a struct combined from all the fields of a record. `struct(b.*) not in (struct(n.*))` is a work around for the unsupported `struct(b.*) != struct(n.*)`. If 2 records have same `id` but `struct(b.*) != struct(n.*)` than there is a difference between the records, therefore an update.

Comment: is it possible to add a flag indicates whether the records are DELETED or INSERTed or UPDATed  and proper column name also  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select      inline(array(rec))

from       (select      max(struct(tab,rec)).col2 as rec

            from        (           select 1 as tab,id,struct(*) as rec from base_table
                        union all   select 2 as tab,id,struct(*) as rec from new_table
                        ) t

            group by    id

            having      count(*) = 1
                    or  min(rec) not in (max(rec))
            ) t
```

---

```
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
| col1 |  col2  |   col3    |  col4   |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
| 2097 | Deny   | Italy     | Rome    |
| 7682 | Stuart | Darmstadt | Germany |
| 9057 | Bony   | Prague    | Prague  |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you add an explanation on how the update records are handled in the above query.

Comment: `struct(*)` is a struct combined from all the fields of a record. `min(rec) not in (max(rec))` is a work around for the unsupported `min(rec) != max(rec)`. If a group of records have the same `id` but `min(rec) != max(rec)` than there are at least to different records in the set, therefore an update.